# How to call a constructor on an already allocated memory?

Tags: c++, constructor

How can I call a constructor on a memory region that is already allocated?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can use the placement new constructor, which takes an address.

```
Foo* foo = new (your_memory_address_here) Foo ();
```

Take a look at a more detailed explanation at the [C++ FAQ lite](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/dtors#placement-new) or the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kewsb8ba.aspx). The only thing you need to make sure that the memory is properly aligned (`malloc` is supposed to return memory that is properly aligned for anything, but beware of things like SSE which may need alignment to 16 bytes boundaries or so).

Comment: For anyone else who stumbles across this:  I had to `#include <new>` before this would work - g++ threw a bunch of unhelpful "no matching function" errors if I didn't.  [This](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/dtors.html#faq-11.10) is the info on placement new (also C++ FAQ) that helped me figure it out.

Comment: "The only thing"  -- there are also other concerns, for example reusing the memory location containing an active object with a non-trivial destructor can lead to undefined behaviour. [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42997440/is-it-legal-to-use-placement-new-on-initialised-memory) for more detail

Comment: @M.M doesn't std::launder solve that ?

Answer (score 5):

Notice that before invoking placement `new`, you need to call the destructor on the memory – at least if the object either has a nontrivial destructor or contains members which have.

For an object pointer `obj` of class `Foo` the destructor can explicitly be called as follows:

```
obj->~Foo();
```

Comment: Why should we call the destructor on the newly allocated memory before doing the placement new ? I dont get it...

Comment: You normally don't get memory that has been allocated but not initialized. If that's indeed what you've got then of course you *must not* call a destructor on it. For all other cases, there is already an object at that location that must be properly disposed of.

Comment: You don't initialize memory(unless you mean setting all zeroes). You initialize objects. Calling dtor on some random memory is bad. Only if you are doing container of objects it would make sense to call dtor. If these objects have empty non-virtual dtor you dont have to do it.

Comment: @ArekBal Object = memory, according to the C++ standard. So you initialise both. Of course if you have *uninitialised* memory you wouldn’t call the destructor (but that’s *still* an object). And like I said in my answer, the presence of an empty destructor isn’t enough to forego calling the destructor, since member variables may have non-trivial destructors.

Answer (score 4):

The placement new constructor mentioned by the accepted answer is an old way before the allocator class defined in  header. Now you really should do(in C++11 style):

```
allocator<Foo> alloc;
//Allocate memory for one or n objects
auto p = alloc.allocate(1); 
//Construct an object of Foo on allocated memory block p, by calling one of Foo's constructors
alloc.construct(p, args, ...); 

//OK, p now points to a Foo object ready for use...

//Call Foo's destructor but don't release memory of p
alloc.destroy(p); 
//Release memory
alloc.deallocate(p, 1);
```

That's it.

Comment: `std::allocator::construct` is for instantiating objects in memory supplied by `std::allocator::allocate`, not arbitrary other sources

Comment: Are you sure? @Caleth

Comment: @Robert In C++20 you can use [`std::construct_at`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/construct_at) and it's not part of `allocator` namespace anymore