# std::allocator_traits::construct with const pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, language-lawyer, allocator

The following code compiles fine:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
int main()
{
const int * a = new int(5);

std::cout << *a << std::endl; // Prints 5

// *a = 5; // Compiler error.
using at = std::allocator_traits<typename std::allocator<int>>;
auto alloc = std::allocator<int>();
at::construct(alloc, a);

std::cout << *a << std::endl; // Prints 0
}
```

Under the hood libstdc++ does

```
::new((void*)a) int;
```

but `a` is `const`!

Is this undefined behavior? Or does placement new not count as modifying?
I modified the value of `*a`, which is const. To my understanding this is not allowed:

> Modifying a const object through a non-const access path and
>   referring to a volatile object through a non-volatile glvalue results
>   in undefined behavior.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast

Comment: This looks like a reasonable dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42997440/is-it-legal-to-use-placement-new-on-initialised-memory.  Not 100% sure so I'll leave it you/the community to decide.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Great! Thank you. Reading trough it.

Comment: @NathanOliver Whether it is legal to use placement-new on initialized memory seems only part of the question. Whether `std::allocator_traits::construct()` is legal is the other part.

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR**: Fine until C++2a, thereafter `std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<int>>::construct()` will be more demanding of the passed pointer.

---

Well, `std::allocator_traits::construct()` [uses `static_cast<void*>` since it was introduced](http://eel.is/c++draft/allocator.traits#members-5), unless the allocator provides it.

And while `std::allocator::construct()` was deprecated in C++17 and will be removed in C++2a, it always used a c-style cast.

Thus, it's syntactically valid until C++2a.

---

And as the pointed-to object itself is not `const`, only the pointer it is accessed through having that qualifier, casting away `const` and modifying is perfectly legal.

As the pseudo-dtor for `int` is trivial, it doesn't even matter that it isn't called before constructing a new one on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

`const int* a` specify that the value contained by the memory slot pointed by `a` is constant, but not the pointer itself.

```
#include <memory>

int main()
{
    const int * a = new int;

    a = nullptr; // Compile fine
    *a = 1; // Won't compile

    return 0;
}
```

You were expecting your code to behave like:

```
#include <memory>

int main()
{
    int* const a = new int;

    a = nullptr; // Won't compile
    *a = 1; // Compile fine

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do note that the pointer is not being changed, it is what it is pointing to that is.

Comment: As @NathanOliver pointed out. I just changed the value stored. I added some `stdout` to clarify this.