# Is new (this) ThisClass() a bad idea?

Tags: c++, placement-new

```
class FooView final : public Something
{
    ...
    void refresh()
    {
        this->~FooView();
        new (this) FooView();
    }
}
```

I have never seen this idiom, and it seems like it could be really subtle and messy, but I can't actually think of a problem with it (as long as `FooView` is final).  Is this a bad idea?

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58274963/placement-new-on-non-pointer-variables-and-class-members.  Can we get the full context of the type?  It does matter.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do that, but you'll need memory laundering for that if you have reference or const members, or if the type of the class changes.

Consider this:

```
struct FooView {
    const int val;

    void refresh()
    {
        this->~FooView();
        new (this) FooView{5};
    }
}

int main() {
    FooView fv{9};

    std::cout << fv.val; // surely 9!
    fv.refresh();
    std::cout << fv.val; // hmm... val is a const object, so it's 9 still?
}
```

To avoid this undefined behaviour, you should launder the memory using [`std::launder`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/launder). The compiler will assume that the lifetime of `fv` won't be affected by anything except `}`. Laundering will make the compiler assume there is an object, unrelated to `fv`:

```
int main() {
    FooView fv{9};

    std::cout << fv.val; // surely 9!
    fv.refresh();
    std::cout << std::launder(&fv)->val; // yay, 5
}
```

Now is it a good idea? I'd advise against it since it can lead to confusion but it can be done safely.