# Accessing C++ class state via Lua wrapper yields garbage values

Tags: c++, lua

I'm trying to expose a simple C++ class to Lua via Lua's C API. I know there are libraries that already solve this problem but I would like to understand how to do this with just the C API.

Here is my program:

```
#define LUA_LIB

#include <cassert>

extern "C"
{
  #include "lua.h"
  #include "lauxlib.h"
}

namespace
{

class Foo
{
public:
  Foo(int state)
  : _state(state)
  {}

  int get_state() const
  { return _state; }

private:
  int _state;
};

int foo_new(lua_State *L)
{
  assert(lua_gettop(L) == 2);

  luaL_checktype(L, 1, LUA_TTABLE);

  lua_newtable(L);
  lua_pushvalue(L, 1);
  lua_setmetatable(L, -2);
  lua_pushvalue(L, 1);
  lua_setfield(L, 1, "__index");

  int state = lua_tointeger(L, 2);

  auto **__obj = static_cast<Foo **>(lua_newuserdata(L, sizeof(Foo *)));
  *__obj = new Foo(state);

  lua_setfield(L, -2, "__self");

  return 1;
}

int foo_get_state(lua_State *L)
{
  assert(lua_gettop(L) == 1);

  luaL_checktype(L, 1, LUA_TTABLE);

  lua_getfield(L, 1, "__self");

  auto *__obj = static_cast<Foo *>(lua_touserdata(L, -1));
  lua_pushinteger(L, __obj->get_state());

  return 1;
}

luaL_Reg const foo_functions[] = {
  {"new", foo_new},
  {"get_state", foo_get_state},
  {nullptr, nullptr}
};

} // namespace

extern "C"
{

LUALIB_API int luaopen_foo(lua_State *L)
{
  luaL_newlib(L, foo_functions);
  lua_setglobal(L, "Foo");

  return 1;
}

} // extern "C"
```

`foo_new` creates a Lua table which stores a C++ `Foo` object as userdata in its `__self` field. I call this function from Lua as `local foo = Foo:new(1)`. That seems to work, however, subsequently calling `print(foo:get_state())` does not return `1` but some garbage value. Why is that and how can I fix it?

Comment: 1. You allocating memory `auto **__obj` in `new`, but acessing as `auto *__obj` in `foo_get_state`. 2. Such allocation makes memory leak after garbage collecting the object - `new Foo()` is never disposed (check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519808/how-to-call-a-constructor-on-an-already-allocated-memory how to access constructor without allocating extra memory)

Comment: Your code in `foo_get_state` must be: `auto **__obj = static_cast<Foo **>(lua_touserdata(L, -1));  lua_pushinteger(L, (*__obj)->get_state());`, don`t forget to check if pointer is valid.

Comment: @Darius: Okay, so other than the memory leak I have mixed up `**__obj` and `*__obj`. I have now just replaced the allocation step by `auto *__obj = new (lua_newuserdata(L, sizeof(Foo))) Foo(state);`. The Lua code now outputs one but it seems like `~Foo` is still not called? Other than that, if you combine your comments into an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 problems:

- You allocating memory `auto **__obj` in lua function `new`, but acessing as `auto *__obj` in lua function `foo_get_state`.
- Memory leak - you're missing functionality to collect garbage for `new Foo()`

It is not good to mix metatable with data object, but in your case it should work like:

```cpp
int foo_new(lua_State *L)
{
  assert(lua_gettop(L) == 2);
  luaL_checktype(L, 1, LUA_TTABLE);

  lua_newtable(L);
  lua_pushvalue(L, 1);
  lua_setmetatable(L, -2);
  lua_pushvalue(L, 1);
  lua_setfield(L, 1, "__index");

  int state = lua_tointeger(L, 2);

  auto *__obj = static_cast<Foo *>(lua_newuserdata(L, sizeof(Foo)));
  new(__obj) Foo(state);
  lua_setfield(L, -2, "__self");

  return 1;
}

int foo_get_state(lua_State *L)
{
  assert(lua_gettop(L) == 1);
  luaL_checktype(L, 1, LUA_TTABLE);

  lua_getfield(L, 1, "__self");
  auto *__obj = static_cast<Foo *>(lua_touserdata(L, -1));
  assert(__obj != nullptr);
  lua_pushinteger(L, __obj->get_state());
  return 1;
}

int foo_gc(lua_State *L)
{
  assert(lua_gettop(L) == 1);
  luaL_checktype(L, 1, LUA_TTABLE);

  lua_getfield(L, 1, "__self");
  auto *__obj = static_cast<Foo *>(lua_touserdata(L, -1));
  if (__obj)
    __obj->~Foo();

  lua_pushnil(L);
  lua_setfield(L, -3, "__self");
  return 0;
}

luaL_Reg const foo_functions[] = {
  {"new", foo_new},
  {"get_state", foo_get_state},
  {"__gc", foo_gc},
  {nullptr, nullptr}
};
```

`__gc` is not necessary if your work with simple data without memory/handles allocations as lua garbage collection frees allocated memory.